# Build a Custom layer that extract certain slice of a tensor based on the input with Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to extract a slice of an input tensor based on the value of another input tensor. But the value in second tensor is not EagerTensor and I don't know how to use its value. Could anyone help me with it please?

My two inputs are of the shape (7,26), (1,1) defined as:

In1 = Input(shape=(1,1))
In2 = Input(shape=(7,26))

In1 is used for passing the index for extracting the slice in In2. I was trying something like this:

class SliceLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
def **init**(self, **kwargs):
super(SliceLayer, self).**init**(**kwargs)

```
def call(self, inputs):

    sliceindex, fullarray = inputs
    sliceindex = sliceindex[0,0]
    slicearray = tf.slice(fullarray, [0,0,sliceindex],[1,7,1])
    return slicearray
```

When I connect it to the inputs with

SliceLayer()([In3,In4])

I got an error:
in call  *        slicearray = tf.slice(fullarray, [0,0,sliceindex],[1,7,1])
Tried to convert 'begin' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1
From merging shape 1 with other shapes.

If I change the line `slicearray = tf.slice(fullarray, [0,0,sliceindex],[1,7,1])` to `slicearray = tf.slice(fullarray, [0,0,0],[1,7,1])` this layer works fine.

It seems that by doing sliceindex = sliceindex[0,0], my sliceindex is still a tensor but not a numpy value. Does anyone know the correct way to build this slicing layer? Thanks a lot for your help!